# Why memset is needed before strptime

Tags: strptime, memset

In order for this code to run properly, memset must be used. Why is that?

```
struct tm temp;
memset(&temp, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
strptime(str.c_str(), "%d-%m-%Y", &temp);
```

Why this is not enough?

```
struct tm temp;
strptime(str.c_str(), "%d-%m-%Y", &temp);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "not enough"? `struct tm` has 9 different fields that are part of the date/time information that `strptime` provides. The function will fill in the fields that it can parse from your string given the format you provide. If you need the other fields that aren't referenced set to 0, then `strptime` expects you to do that yourself. It makes no pre-supposition as to what you want to initialize them to. You might choose to have them set to something else, either from a prior calculation or event.

Comment: With struct tm temp does not tm take over in memory sizeof(struct tm) bytes?
Why do we need memset?

Comment: The memset doesn't allocate the memory. It initializes it to 0. Declaring the struct doesn't initialize it to 0 for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this little snippet in the [`strptime` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) (my emphasis):

> values for the *appropriate* `tm` structure members are set to values corresponding to the locale information.

In other words, it doesn't necessarily set *all* the fields of a `tm` structure, so you initialise everything to zeros first. Otherwise, being a local variable, it's likely to have arbitrary information in all its fields before parsing the time string (and after, unless you're explicitly parsing an appropriate item).

One reason it does this (skipping fields you don't explicitly parse) is because you may already have a `tm` set up and you only want to change certain fields (for example, using `time()` and `localtime()` to get the `tm` for today, and then parsing 5pm to get that specific time for today).

There's a good chance that, if you're only going to be looking at the fields you parsed, you won't have to worry about zeroing first. But there may also be the *possibility* that whoever wrote your `strptime` implementation was "too clever", and decided they could post-massage the data to fix problems. For example, if you have `26:00:00` as the time, and you parse the date for `March 1`, it may adjust it to `March 2, 02:00:00`.

I'm not saying that's likely (or even allowed by the specifications) but, given the minimal cost of zeroing the structure before-hand, I'd probably prefer to be safe. Especially since there are many people out there who *are* "too clever" :-)

Comment: But I do not want to use all fields, only those mentioned in the format in strptime.

Comment: @dklovedoctor then it's possible you may not need to set the rest to 0 with memset. But what's the harm in doing so?